# Tensorflow - Nodegyp failed to build even if it is installed

Tags: python, tensorflow, npm, node-gyp

I am trying to setup `TensorFlow` for a demo application however I have some problems building it i get the following error whenever I `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node` :

```
CPU-windows-2.8.1.zip
* Downloading libtensorflow
[==============================] 34893663/bps 100% 0.0s
* Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings
node-pre-gyp install failed with error: Error: Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v5/2.8.1/CPU-windows-2.8.1.zip
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for @tensorflow/tfjs-node@2.8.1 and node@12.13.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gy
p)
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-
to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\MyUser\\WebstormProjects\\baseball\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v5\\tfjs_binding.node" "--module_name=tfjs_binding"
 "--module_path=C:\\Users\\MyUser\\WebstormProjects\\baseball\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v5" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_b
uild_version=5" "--node_napi_label=napi-v5"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\MyUser\WebstormProjects\baseball\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js bu
ild --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\MyUser\WebstormProjects\baseball\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v5\tfjs_binding.node --module_name=tfjs_binding
 --module_path=C:\Users\MyUser\WebstormProjects\baseball\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v5 --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=5 -
-node_napi_label=napi-v5' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MyUser\WebstormProjects\baseball\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\MyUser\\WebstormProjects\\baseball\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "instal
l" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\MyUser\WebstormProjects\baseball\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Node version: **12.13.0**

My operating system is **Windows**

Python --version:
**Python 2.7.18**

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

**Update**

So I looked through the error and found a tiny detail:

this line:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v5/2.8.1/CPU-windows-2.8.1.zip
```

if I go to that URL I correctly get a 404 (or a not found page)

So it might be that? how to do I find that file?

Comment: I have no clue, but Python 2.7 seems like very old version and I doubt TF supports that Python version anymore.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, disagree with you because the package supports pyton 2.7 according to documents. I think updating the node version and cleaning the npm cache will solve the problem.

Comment: Please have a look at my update

Comment: @MarcRasmussen, take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2758) and accordingly [this steps](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows) to setup your build environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to th Error:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v5/2.8.1/CPU-windows-2.8.1.zip
```

And based on [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2758), It seems that there could be some problem with your prerequisites installation. So probably the following links may helps you to overcome your problem:

[install node-gyp on windows](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows)

[Error installing node-gpu](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2428)(this issue is about gpu but the main problem is same as your problem)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install python 3, with the version of python you have TensorFlow won't build.
https://www.tensorflow.org/install

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and when I used `python 3` instead of `python 2`, it worked for me.
Try installing Python `3.8.3`

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth given my different setup (I'm on macOS Catalina), an `npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node` on a clean project resulted in `node-pre-gyp install failed with error: Error: Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`  because one of the parent of the working folder had spaces in the name. Apparently this still happens in 2021.

Moving to a *more traditional* path solved the issue.